# Is it possible to change to a larger and type of crankset from a one-piece Ashtabula style?

Tags: crankset

I made an E-Bike out of a cheap bike. It uses those one piece cranks. I was wondering if I could get a bigger gear. The motor top speed is 36km/h and I would like to assist the motor while going at that speed. But as is, past 24km/h, it's too fast to allow me to assist.

With this types of crankset I never found anything different than that size gear. If I found some other crankset types would it fit into the frame's crank shaft? Is it standardized?

My bike has a 5 speed derailleur, 20inch wheels. The crank is as seen in the example bike image. Motor is front hub.

[image]

Comment: Consider decreasing the size of the rear cog (ie swap for one with fewer teeth)   Be wary of throwing a lot of money at a low-end bike.

Answer (score 2):

One piece cranks are used on inexpensive adult bikes so larger chainrings should be available as replacement parts. The crank-chainring interface is standardized. See [Sheldon Brown's page on one piece cranks](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/opc.html).

Note that the size of the chainring will be limited by the clearance between it and the drive side chainstay.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the bottom bracket housing for a one-piece crank has a larger diameter than those for 3-piece cranks.  There are conversion kits for making the swap, however -- Google `converting 1 piece crank to 3`.

Answer (score -2):

I have a Sondors Fold X single speed ebike and I spin out at too low a speed. I installed a larger chain ring and it works great.  Bought this one:   53 teeth

[image: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UuJG736ML._SL1001_.jpg from https://www.amazon.ca/Crankset-Horizontal-Square-Aluminum-Bicycles/dp/B07CKFZMX7]

I had to add a couple of chain links to accommodate the larger chainring.

Did the same thing to my Sondors X, 7 speed. I had to turn in the "low" adjustment screw on the derailer to eliminate the two lowest gears, which were too, out of line, to the chain ring. Runs great- don't need the low gears with the hub motor anyway. Goes very fast now.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to bicycles!  This doesn't really answer the question; is it possible for _the bike in the question_?  It appears to have a fix-mounted chainring, so swapping in a larger chainring is not a simple chore.

Comment: You're missing the crux of the question and this has gone off on a tangent.   OP has an ashtabula crank, aka a one-piece crank.  Your link is to a three-piece crankset (where the third piece is the BB axle through the bike frame)  so this doesn't answer the question as asked.